# Generate HTML source code from IE DOM

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, bho

Is there any way to generate HTML source code from live DOM tree in IE?
The DOM may be modified by JavaScript, but I just want the final result.

If I want to write a BHO to do this, which event should I handle such thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```